# Descent theory for higher sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, higher-category-theory

I am trying to understand the descent condition for sheaves from presheaves. Let Presh(S) be the $(\infty,1)$ category of presheaves on an $(\infty,1)$ site S, and Sh(S) be the corresponding category of sheaves. In PreSh(S), we have morphisms W: Y $\rightarrow$ X, the $(\infty,1)$ sheaves A are those $(\infty,1)$ presheaves in PreSh(S) which are local objects with respect to this morphism in this category; these local objects induce bijection between PreSh(S)(X, A) and PreSh(S)(Y, A) in the homotopy category of $\infty$-Top.
Y can be regarded as cover or hypercover with respect to the $(\infty,1)$ presheaf X. Thus, the $(\infty,1)$ sheaf condition descends from Y to X.
But, I have a doubt here. X and Y are objects in PreSh(S); I do not get how Y can be a hypercover which is a morphism in the category Simplicial PreSh(S), not PreSh(S).
Can someone kindly clarify this? I have just completed my undergrad in physics; apologies if this doubt sounds trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start with a hypercover represented as a morphism $Z_\bullet \to c_\bullet X$ in simplicial presheaves, where $c_\bullet X$ denotes the constant simplicial presheaf, then your $Y$ is the colimit (= geometric realization) of $Z_\bullet$.  Since the colimit of $c_\bullet X$ is just $X$, the colimit of $Z_\bullet \to c_\bullet X$ gives you your morphism $Y\to X$ of presheaves.

The point of taking the colimit is that mapping out of colimits takes them to limits, so you have $\mathrm{PreSh}(S)(Y,A) \simeq \lim \mathrm{PreSh}(S)(Z_\bullet, A)$, where the latter is the more straightforwardly defined space of "descent data" in $A$ over the hypercover $Z$.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any generalization to the $(\infty,n)$ case? I have seen localization only for $(\infty,1)$. Thanks!

Comment: @PinakBanerjee: The case of (∞,n)-categories is a special case of sheaves valued in (∞,1)-categories: simply take the (∞,1)-category of (∞,n))-categories as a target.

Comment: You mean internalization n times, right?

Comment: No, he means that instead of sheaves *of* $\infty$-groupoids, you can consider sheaves of objects of $C$ for any $(\infty,1)$-category $C$, and $C$ could be the $(\infty,1)$-category of $(\infty,n)$-categories.  But I'm not sure if that answers your question.  Perhaps it would be best to ask it as a new Question so that you can give more background and explanation of exactly what you do mean.

Comment: I understand. Thanks!